# How to rewrite part of a url using apache rewrite rule?

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, apache2

www.example.com

The site has categories like:

reptiles, vegetables, countries

And pages within each category, with urls like:

www.example.com/reptiles/iguana.html
www.example.com/reptiles/black_mamba.html

Now let's say I want to change the "reptiles" category, renaming it to "lizards".

So I would need a rewrite rule and/or 301 redirect to make sure anyone who goes to the old URL will end up at the new one.

Do I need a rule for every single page (iguana.html, black_mamba.html, etc.), or is there some way I can just specify that any url with "reptiles" should have that part changed to "lizards"?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
RewriteRule ^reptiles\/(.*) lizards/$1 [L,R=301]
```